# checking if closed captions are available on youtube video

Tags: flutter, youtube-api, flutter-dependencies, youtube-iframe-api

I am currently working on my flutter mobile app that uses youtube video player. The thing is that I want to programmatically check if the video by url has closed captions available. If the video has closed captions/subtitles, I want to know what languages are available.
Any ideas on how to do this using flutter packages, or which API I should use?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below URL, it will bring the available captions

```
https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?&lang=en&type=list&v=Hu4Yvq-g7_Y
```

just change Hu4Yvq-g7_Y with your video ID.

Comment: This has stopped working recently. Response is now coming as empty. Any ideas to still get the response?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar and had the same issue, they added more parameters to the query so now it is a bit more complicated.

Here are two working examples of the same request with the new parameters:

1. Standard 
   https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=Hu4Yvq-g7_Y&caps=asr&opi=112496729&xoaf=5&hl=en&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1690160643&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,v,caps,opi,xoaf&signature=D514A15E56FDB529431841FE9935E27E838A4031.C44F37530F98D8E106812165DAEBCC3DE5EFE087&key=yt8&lang=en
2. More elaborated including return format 
   https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=Hu4Yvq-g7_Y&caps=asr&opi=112496729&xoaf=5&hl=en&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1688684628&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,v,caps,opi,xoaf&signature=56611CE47782703DDED0CECA970F8D604793E4D9.773F5F205C8B2215C403CE346388E3ED7B1BA5A6&key=yt8&kind=asr&lang=en&fmt=json3&xorb=2&xobt=3&xovt=3&cbr=Chrome&cbrver=114.0.0.0&c=WEB&cver=2.20230703.08.00&cplayer=UNIPLAYER&cos=Windows&cosver=10.0&cplatform=DESKTOP

Special attention to the expire and signature.

So far they only work for me if I do the post from the browser and need to capture it again every time I load a new video on the same page because YouTube site doesn't reload pages on navigation, it replaces the history state.

Hope this helps.